# Как предотвратить логин более одного раза от одного юзера в node js

Tags: node.js, express

Вопрос таков, как ограничить логин под одного пользователя. То есть , если пользователь зашел под свой аккаунт и параллельно кто-то пытается под него зайти, вывело какую то ошибку наподобие - Юзер уже онлайн или активен. Использую я `ExpressJS` и `PassportJS` для аутентификации. Есть ли к нему уже готовые решения?

З.Ы не ругайтесь на структуру вопроса, заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Заложи некое время активности. Пиши в дополнительное поле таблицы пользователей штамп времени последнего действия. При логауте - сбрасывай в Null или там в 1900-й год... Если при логине разность между текущим и сохранённым временем меньше выбранного времени активности - отказ.

Comment: А что если логаут не сделает юзер, получается под этот аккаунт он не зайдет, пока там в поле не будет указано дефолтное значение?

Comment: *А что если логаут не сделает юзер* А почему ты должен решать проблемы, которые юзер сам себе создал? Не, если хочется, сделай ещё и вход с двойной аутентификацией, который принудительно сбрасывает флаг активности...

Comment: Для начала стоит серьёзно подумать зачем это надо.  И даже если действительно надо, то обычно в таком случае побеждает последний логин, а не первый.